# Python, create a kind of template for functions

Tags: python, function, templates

I have a class with three functions that do almost the same things but on different objects. And I think there is a better way to program it since it is a duplication of code, but I cannot see how to have a kind of template. Here is my example:

```py
    def averageEndEffectorVelocity(self, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
        if len(self.eeVelocity) < samplingSize:
            return -1
        else:
            return sum(self.eeVelocity[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize

    def averageEndEffectorAcceleration(self, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
        if len(self.eeAcceleration) < samplingSize:
            return -1
        else:
            return sum(self.eeAcceleration[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize

    def averageEndEffectorJerk(self, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
        if len(self.eeJerk) < samplingSize:
            return -1
        else:
            return sum(self.eeJerk[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize
```

One can see that each function is calculating the average of the last `samplingSize` values of the velocity, acceleration and jerk. Is there a way to have a better code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this function work fully on parameters passed to it (can be made class or static method, or refactored outside of the class completely):

```
def averageEndEffector(data, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
    if len(data) < samplingSize:
        return -1
    else:
        return sum(data[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize
```

Now all your instance methods can simply take the form of:

```
    def averageEndEffectorVelocity(self, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
        return averageEndEffector(data=self.eeVelocity, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE)
```

Comment: Ohhh it's really simple! I didn't though about creating another function and calling it from the others! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine to one method like this

```
def averageEndEffector(self, effector, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
    value = getattr(self, effector)
    if len(value) < samplingSize:
        return -1
    else:
        return sum(value[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize
```

effector can be eeVelocity, eeAcceleration or eeJerk (You can remove 'ee' and add this prefix to getattr function and it's better to use const)

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
def averageEndParameter(self, whichQuantity, samplingSize=cst.AVERAGE_SIZE):
    if (whichQuantity not in ["eeVelocity", "eeAcceleration", "eeJerk"]): # List of known Parameters
        return -1
    if len(self.__getattribute__(whichQuantity)) < samplingSize:
        return -1
    else:
        return sum(self.__getattribute__(whichQuantity)[-samplingSize:])/samplingSize
```

Use it like this :

```
averageEndParameter("eeVelocity")
averageEndParameter("eeAcceleration")
averageEndParameter("eJerk")
```

You can extend this to Newer Parameters by adding those Items to the List of known Parameters.